# Integral in spherical coordinates.

Tags: integration, spherical-coordinates

I have to evaluate the following integral
$$\int_{-2}^{2}\int_{0}^{\sqrt{4-y^2}}\int_{-\sqrt{4-x^2-y^2}}^{\sqrt{4-x^2-y^2}}y^2\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}dzdxdy$$
using spherical coordinates.

For me, the region is the part of the sphere of radius 2 located in the 1º, 4º, 5º and 8º octants. If
$$\begin{array}{l}x=\rho\sin\phi\cos\theta \\ y=\rho\sin\phi\sin\theta \\ z=\rho\cos\phi \end{array}$$
then
$$0\leq\rho\leq2,\qquad0\leq\phi\leq\pi,\qquad-\pi\leq\theta\leq\pi$$
which gives me
$$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}\int_{0}^{2}\rho^{5}\sin^{3}\phi\sin^{2}\theta d\rho d\phi d\theta$$

The first integral, according to Wolfram is equal to
$$\frac{64\pi}{9}$$
but when I evaluate the one with spherical coordinates, I get
$$\frac{128\pi}{9}$$
What is wrong?

Comment: your sphere covers all the octants. How can you change the bounds so that it's not?

Comment: @NinadMunshi but what does mean $0<x<\sqrt{4-y^2}$ then?

Comment: I said your sphere, not the problem's. Fix your bounds.

Comment: @NinadMunshi Oh, I found my problem. Thanks!